# bike identification help to buy

Tags: identify-this-bike

I'm trying to find this base model of the bike, someone is selling this one with a Bafang kit.

[image]

Comment: What do the other stickers say?   I see a name badge with a Canadian flag, not that one.  I'm curious about the floral cursive thing on the downtube, looks like "MADDYGUARD" ?

Comment: Have you asked the seller?

Answer (score 8):

1. What do you need this information for?
2. I'm pretty sure that despite the BMC label on the downtube, this is not really a BMC. BMCs of this vintage typically had a little extra buttress below the seat clamp. BMCs are also pretty high-end bikes, and this has some visibly low-end parts.

So I think this is probably an anonymous bike with a fancy label.